# Single android application with two tasks and its navigation

Tags: android, navigation, task, back-stack, launchmode

I am developing a calling application. My HomeActivity is a singleTask activity. My call activity is also a singleTask activity.

From HomeActivity a call is initiated. At this moment, there are two tasks for my application as they both are singleTask. In call screen I have a button to reach my HomeActivity.

When I press the home button in my call screen and navigate back, my call activity is destroyed. But it should not get destroyed. It should remain.

When I press home button in call screen I do the below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.setClass(this.getActivity(), MyHomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

My manifest declaration:

```
<activity
    android:name=".XXX.MyHomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".XXX.MyCallActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Inflating HomeActivity from CallActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this.getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inflating CallActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, CallActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone help me with the navigation parameters to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have 2 tasks, you need to make sure that the root `Activity` of the tasks have different `taskAffinity`, otherwise Android will put both in the same task. The default `taskAffinity` is the name of your package.

Add `android:taskAffinity=""` to one of the `<activity>` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK will do the following:

> this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with
>   the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is,
>   the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any
>   old activities are finished.

So if want your CallActivity to stay in the back stack you can simply do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this.getActivity(), MyHomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Umang, I tried this now. Even in this case, my CallActivity is getting destroyed and I dont understand why. I also tried "intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);". No use though.

Comment: would be great if you can share the manifest declaration of both the activities along with the code used to inflate them

Comment: using the above declaration second activity is not getting killed. check if you have called finish() somewhere

Comment: If you are interested, you can run this sample app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LRh_ZR9gI-Yk1Fd0N5em1aNjg/view?usp=sharing   .My problem is why CallActivity is getting destroyed.

Comment: I solved this by making the call activity as "singleInstance". But I am not getting a logical explanation as to why the call activity is getting killed.